Possibility of a fan with two switches being wired to one switch
I moved into a new house last year, built in the 1970s (I think it was 76?) Long story short, in the living room I have a bank of three switches. One controls some recessed lighting, one controls the fan/light (along with some random outlets but thats beside the point), and the third switch I have no clue what it does. I have already checked all other outlets in the room and lights in surrounding rooms and can't figure it out.
My best guess is that the fan/light is meant to have two switches, one for light one for fan, but I am not sure if it is possible to wire a fan and light combo to a single switch when it was meant to be two. I imagine that might be okay and the other switch is just fully disconnected and serves no purpose at this point, but I am not familiar enough with electrical to know if this is correct.
I believe the fan was replaced by the previous owners but can not guarantee, I am mostly basing this guess off of my estimate of the age of the fan as compared to the age of the house.
To sum up the question, is it possible that an older fan, wired to two switches, was replaced with a fan that was wired to a single switch and the other switch is now useless and does not pose any electrical risk? How to confirm that this is the case?

All of that is possible. As are a number of other possibilities. The only way to figure it out is to check the wiring. The starting point on that is the wires to the switches and any other wires in the same boxes. Turn off the breaker so that the known devices no longer turn on. Because there is an unknown switch which might be on a different breaker, do NOT proceed without a non-contact voltage tester such as this Klein from Amazon (stick with name brands UL or ETL listed) so that you can remove the faceplates and then check for hot wires before removing

switches. Then, assuming nothing is "hot" (electrically), unscrew the switches from their boxes. Do NOT remove ANY wires from anything, just pull the switches out and take pictures of the wires going to the switches and the wires in the back of the box(es). Then upload the pictures and we can try to figure this out.

@manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact thank you, I'll try and get those pictures later today. I'll likely just turn off the entire breaker box for safety

@murrag is it possible? is a pointless question because the answer is always a yes

@jsotola So I can expect your delivery of Upsidasium, the antigravity metal yesterday by time machine powered by perpetual motion machine and entropy reversal? ;^)
